# automation create openstack (Havana) script for Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack, openstack-horizon

Hi and thanks in advance,

I Was wondering if there is a known automation script to create openstack Havana directly without having to use a vm ( virtualbox or vmware) on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. I am aware of vagrant and I have used it, but it seems like i need to a vm. If I am wrong please let me know.

Comment: Currently looking at a couple manual install sites: [https://github.com/fornyx/OpenStack-Havana-Install-Guide/blob/master/OpenStack-Havana-Install-Guide.rst#21-preparing-ubuntu] & [http://virtual2privatecloud.com/install-havana-on-ubuntu/]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Devstack](http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html). You can run openstack on a single class machine or a laptop at home using devstack.